# Using tidymodels in R, my BART workflow changes after I fit it once. Why?

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-parsnip, bart

I have been trying to train a BART model using the [tidymodels](https://www.tidymodels.org/) framework but I am running into some problems.

I can declare the model, the recipe, and the workflow alright, but once I fit the workflow, two unwanted things happen:

1. The *original* model object (`bart_mod` below), initially correctly stored, becomes "`call: NULL`", even though I don't touch the model object directly (I assign nothing to the same object name).
2. I am not able to retrieve any information about the fitted model. The `bart_fit` contains nothing and there seems to be no tidy method associated to it. All this is true even though I am able to predict values using the fitted model! (See last line of code in the reprex).

This may very well come from a misunderstanding of how all this works on my end, I am fairly new to tidymodels.

I would appreciate any help! Thank you.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

set.seed(2022)

# Parameters --------------------------------------------------------------

n <- 5000

coef_x_var_1 <- 1
coef_x_var_2 <- 2
coef_x_var_3 <- 3

gen_y_1 <- function(data = dataset) {
  
  return(data$y_0 +
           data$x_var_1*coef_x_var_1 +
           data$x_var_2*coef_x_var_2 +
           data$x_var_3*coef_x_var_3 +
           rnorm(n = nrow(data), mean = 0, sd = 3)
  )}

# Data generation ---------------------------------------------------------

dataset <- matrix(NA, nrow = n, ncol = 3)

# Generate the unit-level moderators
dataset[,1] <- rnorm(mean = rnorm(n = 1), n = n)
dataset[,2] <- rnorm(mean = rnorm(n = 1), n = n)
dataset[,3] <- rnorm(mean = rnorm(n = 1), n = n)

# Change into dataframe
colnames(dataset) <- c("x_var_1", "x_var_2", "x_var_3")
dataset <- as_tibble(dataset)

# Make sure the variable format is numeric (except for the identifiers)
dataset$x_var_1 <- as.numeric(dataset$x_var_1)
dataset$x_var_2 <- as.numeric(dataset$x_var_2)
dataset$x_var_3 <- as.numeric(dataset$x_var_3)

# Generate the untreated potential outcomes
P0_coefs <- rdunif(n = 6,  1, 15)
dataset$y_0 <-
  dataset$x_var_1*P0_coefs[4] +
  dataset$x_var_2*P0_coefs[5] +
  dataset$x_var_3*P0_coefs[6] +
  rnorm(n = nrow(dataset), mean = 0, sd = 3)

dataset$y_1 <- gen_y_1(data = dataset)

# Create a variable to indicate treatment
treatment_group <- sample(1:nrow(dataset), size = nrow(dataset)/2)
# Indicate which potential outcome you observe
obs_dataset <- dataset |> 
  mutate(treated = ifelse(row_number() %in% treatment_group, 1, 0),
         obs_y = ifelse(treated, y_1, y_0))

y1_obs_dataset <- obs_dataset |> filter(treated == 1)
y0_obs_dataset <- obs_dataset |> filter(treated == 0)

# Analysis ----------------------------------------------------------------

covariates <- c("x_var_1", "x_var_2", "x_var_3")
bart_formula <- as.formula(paste0("obs_y ~ ", paste(covariates, collapse = " + ")))

# Create the workflow
bart_mod <- bart() |> 
  set_engine("dbarts") |> 
  set_mode("regression")

bart_recipe <- recipe(bart_formula, data = obs_dataset) |> 
  step_zv(all_predictors())

bart_workflow <- 
  workflow() |> 
  add_model(bart_mod) |> 
  add_recipe(bart_recipe)

# The workflow first looks right
bart_workflow
#> ══ Workflow ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
#> Preprocessor: Recipe
#> Model: bart()
#> 
#> ── Preprocessor ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> 1 Recipe Step
#> 
#> • step_zv()
#> 
#> ── Model ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> BART Model Specification (regression)
#> 
#> Computational engine: dbarts

# Once I fit it though, the model part becomes call: NULL
bart_fit <- bart_workflow |> 
  fit(y1_obs_dataset)

# Nothing is stored in the fit
bart_fit
#> ══ Workflow [trained] ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
#> Preprocessor: Recipe
#> Model: bart()
#> 
#> ── Preprocessor ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> 1 Recipe Step
#> 
#> • step_zv()
#> 
#> ── Model ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> 
#> Call:
#> `NULL`()

# The content of this object has changed!
bart_workflow
#> ══ Workflow ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
#> Preprocessor: Recipe
#> Model: bart()
#> 
#> ── Preprocessor ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> 1 Recipe Step
#> 
#> • step_zv()
#> 
#> ── Model ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> 
#> Call:
#> NULL

bart_fit |>
  extract_fit_parsnip(bart_fit)
#> parsnip model object
#> 
#> 
#> Call:
#> `NULL`()

# And yet, I am able to run a prediction using the fit!
predict(bart_fit, y0_obs_dataset)
#> # A tibble: 2,500 × 1
#>      .pred
#>      <dbl>
#>  1  -4.67 
#>  2  -6.23 
#>  3   6.35 
#>  4  10.7  
#>  5   4.90 
#>  6 -13.8  
#>  7   4.70 
#>  8  19.6  
#>  9  -0.907
#> 10   5.38 
#> # … with 2,490 more rows
```

Created on 2022-12-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)

Comment: If you do  `print_model_spec(bart_mod)` you get `BART Model Specification (regression)

Computational engine: dbarts`. If you do `print(bart_mod)` you get `Call:
NULL`. `bart_mod[["engine"]]` returns `dbarts`. So the list for bart_mod is correct, but it doesn't display correctly.

Comment: In case it's relevant, bart is in both the parsnip and the dbarts namespaces.

Comment: Testing print(bart_mod), x is NULL inside the print function.

Comment: Thanks Isaiah! I had noticed that the namespace is the same. From what you write I understand the results are still stored correctly, but that the printing fails. Am I understanding this correctly?

What I am eventually trying to do is to summarize information about the models fits (not use them to predict), which is why I am trying to retrieve them (as I would do with `summary(lm_fit)` for a fit from `lm()`).

Comment: Yes, that's what seems to be happening. I didn't get any further as to why.

Comment: `req_pkgs(bart_mod), print_model_spec(bart_mod), bart_mod[["engine"]], bart_mod[["mode"]]` all return sensible values.
The workflow has the recipe `bart_workflow[["pre"]][["actions"]][["recipe"]]`.
The fit object has sensible values `bart_fit[["fit"]][["fit"]][["fit"]][["y"]]`, and you could predict using that object.
But `print(bart_mod)`, `print(bart_workflow)`,  `print(bart_fit)` returns "NULL" for the model spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First stripping Martin's code down to a smaller script:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
set.seed(2022)

obs_dataset <- structure(list(x_var_1 = c(-0.273203786163623, 0.0026566250757164, 
                                          -0.544359413888551, 0.569128408034224, -2.00048700105319, -0.159113741655834
), obs_y = c(-8.14952415680873, 1.91364235165124, -7.68391811408719, 
             -9.01497463720505, -18.5017189874949, -13.505685812581)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                     -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
bart_formula <- as.formula("obs_y ~ x_var_1")

# Create the workflow
bart_mod <- bart() |> 
  set_engine("dbarts") |> 
  set_mode("regression")

bart_recipe <- recipe(bart_formula, data = obs_dataset)

bart_workflow <- 
  workflow() |> 
  add_model(bart_mod) |> 
  add_recipe(bart_recipe)
```

The workflow at first looks right

```
bart_workflow

> ══ Workflow
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> Preprocessor: Recipe Model: bart()
> 
> ── Preprocessor
> ────────────────────────── 0 Recipe Steps
> 
> ── Model
> ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> BART Model Specification (regression)
> 
> Computational engine: dbarts
```

but this changes after fitting:

```
bart_fit <- bart_workflow |> 
  fit(obs_dataset)
bart_fit
```

The workflow now displays NULL for the call, as does the model object.

```
bart_workflow
bart_mod
```

> ```
> ══ Workflow [trained] ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> Preprocessor: Recipe
> Model: bart()
>
> ── Preprocessor ─────────────────────────────────
> 0 Recipe Steps
>
> ── Model ────────────────────────────────────────────────
>
> Call:
> `NULL`()
> ```

All these display values:

```
required_pkgs(bart_mod)
print_model_spec(bart_mod)
bart_mod[["engine"]]
bart_mod[["mode"]]

extract_recipe(bart_fit)
extract_preprocessor(bart_fit)
extract_mold(bart_fit)
bart_fit[["fit"]][["fit"]][["spec"]][["engine"]]
bart_fit[["fit"]][["fit"]][["spec"]][["mode"]]
```

These display NULL:

```
print(bart_mod)
print(bart_workflow)
print(bart_fit)
extract_fit_engine(bart_fit)
extract_fit_parsnip(bart_fit)
extract_model(bart_fit)
```

So, it seems that the model data is still in the objects,
and is useable,
but the print calls do not display it,
and the extract functions do not display it.